# Android in-app-purchase Authentication is required. you need to sign in to your Google account

Tags: android, authentication, in-app-purchase

I have developed an app which requires in-app- purchase, i follow steps as per requirement,

but after completing i got error like:

```
    "Authentication is required. you need to sign in to your google account"
```

I have checked following things,

1. licence key
2. signed apk upload/publish to alpha testing
3. product id
4. testing email accounts

though i am getting same error message: "Authentication is required. you need to sign in to your Google account".

What should i do now?

Will there be more details ?

Thank you in advance.

Any Help very  Appreciated.

Comment: that is point i checked

Comment: sorry i am not good in english, i am french, you not get any thing clear  please ask and giving answeres

Comment: @JosephMekwan:I think the problem is with ur google devloper console you have to publish ur app on alpha or beta and after that you have to test with ur tester approve account...hope it works

Comment: it not possbile to post my question by my  manager, i edit my answeres please see

Comment: @JosephMekwan:Have u try with suggestion in the above comment.?

Comment: ya  @Born this app published as alpha testing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73246/discussion-between-born-to-win-and-joseph-mekwan).

Comment: it is necessary to publish app on alpha testing for in-app-purchase ?
currently it is in draft ?